# How to change the value of certain indices of a numpy array to 0?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to set the values of array elements to 0 in a numpy array +/- 50 from a certain index. I have a numpy array named `proc_ranges` and I am using `numpy.put()` to do this:

```
proc_ranges = numpy.put(proc_ranges,[closest_point_index-50:closest_point_index+50], 0)
```

I am getting a syntax error at the ":", but this seems like the correct way to do this according to the syntax outlined [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this instead

```
proc_ranges[closest_point_index-50:closest_point_index+50] = 0
```

Yeah, you just need to make sure that the value `closest_point_index-50` or`closest_point_index+50` do not exceed the array size.

Comment: That's really why np.put could be interesting here, since it can handle these out of bound errors. Not sure that is the reason for using them here, or if it necessary though